# How to use firestore rules to limit users based on custom claims and date of document?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

So for example I have 2 kinds of custom claims which are `isAdmin` and `isModerator`, and I have a collection of documents which have a `createdAt` field in each document.

For admins, I want them to be able to read all documents in the collection regardless of the `createdAt` of the document. But for moderators, they should only be able to read documents that was created in the last 3 months. How can I modify the Firestore rules to match these conditions?

Right now what I have is something like:

```
match /invoices/{invoiceId} {
    allow read, create, update: if isModerator();
}
```

and note that users with admin custom claim means that they have `isModerator` set to true as well. So the rule above also apply to them. And I know we can set a time based function such as below:

```
function isNewerThan3Months() {
  return request.time < resource.data.createdAt + duration.value(90, 'd')
}
```

But I don't know how can I combine them. If I combine that such as:

```
match /invoices/{invoiceId} {
    allow read, create, update: if isModerator() && isNewerThan3Months();
}
```

Won't this `isNewerThan3Months` also apply to admins?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want allow the access if *either* the user is a moderator *or* the document is less than 3 months old, so:

```
allow read, create, update: if isModerator() || isNewerThan3Months();
```

Keep in mind that [security rules don' filter data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#rules_are_not_filters), so you will have to replicate this logic in your query to ensure the rules allow the operation.